# How to: Zeppelin + boto3 + AWS Credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, apache-zeppelin

I have a VM with Zeppelin that is a shared environment. I want to add `boto3` so I can do some python against AWS. Since zeppelin is running as a service, where would I add the AWS credentials? Would it be in the root's home? Or the home account the service is running under? Or within Zeppelin's user can they supply their own AWS credentials?

I did `pip install boto3` on the OS and then tried in a notebook to import it and I got a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'` error.

Looking for guidance from anyone who has gotten their zeppelin to work with AWS.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux-al2017.html

Answer (score 0):

Zeppelin can be installed in several ways , which could point to the root cause of the issue :

1. via the tar file download - in that case @mootmoot's way is right . boto3 should be configured with the appropriate python interpreter
2. via docker image - in that case you need to add the python module to the docker image itself :

2.a. you can use 'docker exec -i -t  bash\sh(your preference)'
2.b pip install